# Can anyone tell me the name of a book about a boy with an amber ring who accidentally kills a boy with it and eventually turns out to be a chaos god

Tags: story-identification, books

It's the first in a series of fantasy books.

The boy has a ring that he doesn't know is magic. He gets into a fight one day with another boy and ends up accidentally killing him with the power of the ring. He then gets transported by the ring somewhere else and eventually ends up learning that he is a chaos god and his power was trapped in the amber stone of the ring.

There is a love interest at some point as well maybe? She might end up dying and getting resurrected, or something like that.

There's a lot more than goes on in it but I can't remember!

Book is likely to be from the 80s or early 90s.

Answer (score 11):

This is probably [*The Initiate*](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?7151) (1985) by Louise Cooper, the first book in her *Time Master* trilogy.

[image: Cover of "The Initiate" showing a blue-robed figure in a wintry, rocky landscape]

A review [on Goodreads](https://www.goodreads.com/review/show/134358524) confirms some details:

> Into this eternal battle for supremacy comes Tarod, a dark-haired outcast with a power he does not understand. During an innocent game, **he accidentally uses this power against his cousin, killing him instantly** and arousing the wrath of the populace who chase Tarod through the streets and right into a warp storm.

Another notes the ring Tarod always wears, and that Tarod is destined to become an avatar of Chaos.

Comment: There were, IIRR, two other trilogies in that series/world - which were excellent. I don't remember this one, or that Tarod had an origin-story - I'll have to see if I can find it again. He was definitely the coolest character in the series. :)